# OpenJ9 and docker containers?

Tags: openj9

Historically, HotSpot had poor record running in docker containers misjudging the resources allocated (for example RAM). However, things are slowly improving.

How is OpenJ9 aligned with docker containers and to what extent it is aware of the container-provided resources (memory, sockets, threads, etc.)

Also, during the JavaOne 2017 presentation it was mentioned that OpenJ9 can cache jit-compiled classes across different OpenJ9 VMs. Is this shared cache possible when the VMs are confined to different containers (or) if the containerized JVMs share a docker volume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Container support is currently being worked on, for cgroup awareness, please check this [PR](https://github.com/eclipse/omr/pull/1424). This will lead upto adding container support as well.
2. With regards to the Shared Class Cache (SCC), both scenarios are possible. Please see "Using the Class Data Sharing feature" from [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/ibmjava/) for an example of sharing a docker volume. When the JVMs are confined to different containers with no shared volume, it is recommended to build the docker container with the SCC pre-built. You dockerfile will look like this.

   FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk9-openj9:x86_64-alpine-jdk-9.181

   RUN mkdir /opt/shareclasses
       && mkdir /opt/app

   COPY japp.jar /opt/app

   CMD ["java", "-Xshareclasses:cacheDir=/opt/shareclasses", "-jar", "/opt/app/japp.jar"]

You would then need to build and run the image and commit the resultant container and make that as your base image.

`docker build -t japp:latest .
docker run japp
docker commit container_id japp`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to **create a Shared classes cache and include it in the Docker file**.

The Shared classs cache **can be created in a dev or pre-prod environment, or while runing some tests** on the application. 
Creating  the **cache in Pre-prod might be more effective**, **but dooing it with tests** during the build process **is much simpler**. 
I tested it with a Spring Boot application, and **even the simple "contextLoads" test** which is included with any newly generated Spring Boot project **makes a huge difference**.

Here is an **example with tests using Maven**, but the same VM options can be used in different scenarios as well.

**1. Running tests with shared classes cache enabled**:

You can do it in Maven with the Surefire plugin, I'm not sure how can this be done with Gradle

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <argLine>-Xquickstart -Xshareclasses:cacheDir=classCache,name=appname -Xscmx32m </argLine>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**VM Arguments: -Xquickstart -Xshareclasses:cacheDir=classCache,name=appname -Xscmx32m**

- The **cacheDir** sub option is there to **specify the cache folder** to make it easier to include in the Docker image
- The **name** sub option is there to **avoid** the hardly predictable **automatic cache name**
- **-Xscmx** option is there to **limit the cache size**, this should be tuned for the application, there is a tradeoff between startup speed and image size
- **-Xquickstart** option instructs the JVM to **do as much AOT as possible** when used combined with the -Xshareclasses option

You can check **how much of the cache size is used** with the **printStats** subOption like this: java -jar -Xshareclasses:cacheDir=classCache,name=appname,readonly,printStats application.jar

**2. Add prewarmed cache to the Docker image**

Simply **add the directory set by the cacheDir sub option to the image** in this case classCache

```
ADD classCache classCache
```

Since these files will change every single time, classCache **should be added last to the image**

And **run the application with the cache**

```
ENTRYPOINT exec java -Xquickstart -Xtune:virtualized -Xshareclasses:cacheDir=classCache,name=appname,readonly -jar application.jar
```

**VM Arguments: -Xquickstart -Xtune:virtualized -Xshareclasses:cacheDir=classCache,name=appname,readonly -jar application.jar**

The cache can be specified with the **classCache and name sub options**, **without these the JVM might create a new cache folder and ignore the one added to the image.**

According to my experience the **readonly** option makes it a bit **faster**, but it's not strictly necessary. Since this cache will be dropped when the container is destroyed it's not necessary to persist the canges.

**-Xquickstart and -Xtune:virtualized** options are there to further **optimize startup speed in the container**